# Replace Promise

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await

I have a piece of code like this:

```
export default function imageProcessing() {
  return async function (ctx, next) {
    /* some code is here */
    const request = new Promise(resolve => protocol.get(imageUrl, resolve));
    const result = await request;
    if (result.statusCode >= 400) {
      ctx.status = result.statusCode;
      return next();
    }
    ctx.status = result.statusCode;
    /* some more code in between */
    ctx.type = `image/${format}`;
    ctx.body = result.pipe(transformer);
  };
}
```

Eslint is showing me some error(because promise is not allowed).
Error:

> ESLint: Promise is not supported in Opera Mobile 12, Opera Mini all,
>   IE Mobile 10, IE 9, Blackberry Browser 7 (compat/compat)

I can't modify/avoid that because it is strictly prohibited. How can I replace Promise? Can someone rectify this?

Comment: `async`/`await` is syntactic sugar over Promises, and is only available on newer versions of ECMAScript than Promises. I'd appreciate it if you could confirm, but if your Eslint linter is complaining about Promises, I think the only option is to remove Promise/async/await and work only with callback functions.

Comment: @JeffBowman ok removed that clause. Googling...I will try to read more.

Comment: @NaMo Which eslint rule is showing error?

Comment: @Prakashsharma compat/compat: 2

Comment: Just use a transpiler and a promise polyfill (and [declare that in your linter settings](https://github.com/amilajack/eslint-plugin-compat/wiki/Adding-polyfills)). You *really* do not want to rewrite this code (and everything that uses it).

Comment: @Bergi the code based on promise is like 15-30 lines only. So is adding a polyfill bright idea?

Comment: @NaMo You are exporting this function. Not using promises breaks your interface.

Answer (score 1):

Probably,

1. ESLint configuration change is need of the hour for your project.
2. ESlint message is correct, Promises aren't available in those browsers, but so is 'export', async/await and template literal (`image/${format}`). You ll need to remove them as well.
3. If in any case you want to replace the code, check [Babel-Repl](https://babeljs.io/repl), paste your code and check for alternative code to it. ( which will be worst code as per readability)
4. As suggested give transpilers a shot. It is by far best way to overcome this problem of compatibility, but will also ask you to change ESlint settings.
5. A direct convertion without understanding above 4 points,

   ```
   protocol.get(imageUrl, function(result){

   if (result.statusCode >= 400) {
     ctx.status = result.statusCode;
     return next();
   }
   ctx.status = result.statusCode;
   /* some more code in between */
   ctx.type = `image/${format}`;
   ctx.body = result.pipe(transformer);
   }));
   ```

Again this is bound to error-prone future.
Please focus on #1 to solve this problem.